# SSIS - Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FACT_TABLE'

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup, data-warehouse, fact

I know that we can't have duplicate records in Fact Table but I'm very new in SQL Integration Services and I'm looking for a package that can recognize that if the surrogate keys already exists in fact tables...

In this moment I've this package:

[image]

Each lookup objects get the business key of each dimension in my datawarehouse.

At the first time it run very well because in Fact Table I don't have records, but next I made the test and I run the same data again (because in future I want to run this package every 10 minutes so it will get the same data ofentimes) and I get the following error (that I understand very well I want to build an approach to handle this automatically):

> [Load into dbo_DimCI [144]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_FACT_FACT_TABLE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FACT_TABLE'. The duplicate key value is (337, 44, 3, 19, 4682, 12).".

Which objects I need to insert in my package in order to handle this error?

Comment: You could achieve this in several ways, for example one way would be to add another lookup but this time lookup against your fact table records on the keys making up the primary key of your fact table. Another way would be to  filter the source records down to only new rows rather than existing rows. Or if this is just an example/student project, you could delete everything from the fact table in a delete statement you can run this time and time again.

Comment: @Rich thanks! No, this is a profissional case ;) The lookup that you suggest is after the last lookup and put not matching records? Do you have any example?

Comment: Yes that's right. I haven't got an example, no.

Comment: @Rich with that lookup it's taking a lot of time... do you think this is a good approach?

Comment: No, it's just one way. Another way is to just bring in new rows in the source, either by finding a way of selecting only the rows since last time, or if the source is on the same server, doing a join to the fact table in the source. Or deleting all the facts and loading again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates in SSIS Data Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430282/remove-duplicates-in-ssis-data-flow)

Comment: @TabAlleman that post did not respond to my question

Comment: You're right, the subject line looked right, but the question is different.  Here's a better duplicate.   By the way a simple google search produced an entire page of duplicates on Stack Overflow alone:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271555/ignore-duplicate-records-in-ssis-ole-db-destination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your intention is to load only the deltas in each load.

Which means if a record already exists in the fact table, then the record should not be inserted again.

You could achieve this by using a Merge Query.

I do not have an example to load a fact table, but I can point you to an example of a post that talks about loading a Type 2 Dim Table.

Check this link:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2883/using-the-sql-server-merge-statement-to-process-type-2-slowly-changing-dimensions/

You should be able to use such a statement in your SSIS package to update your fact table.

Happy to answer any further questions.

Cheers 
Nithin